# Cambiar el Background de blazor server

Tags: blazor

Hola que tal me gustaría cambiar el background general de el entorno de blazor server, pero me cambie a .net 8 y la pagina _host ya no existe y en la pagina app.razor que viene en la version .net 8 esta en lazado un css.me dirigido a ese css cambio el background y no realiza ningun cambio, tambien antes enlazaba mis css desde _host pero ha hora lo hago desde app.razor me lee el css pero no realiza cambios no lo entiendo.